# Passing data from view to controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I understand that passing record ids through the url isn't usually a good idea, but I am wondering how I can avoid it in my case:

My objective is to list job statuses on a user dashboard and allow users to adjust the status.

I create my view and pass variables to it using the session:

userController.php

```
public function getdashboard()
    {
       //reading the user information
    $arrPageData['user'] = Sentry::getUser();
       //reading the job interviews
    $arrPageData['jobInterviews'] = JobInterview::readCurrentInterviews($this->userID);

    return View::make('clients.dashboard', $arrPageData);
    }
```

This part works great and I don't use the record id in the route. I iterate through the jobInterviews in the dashboard view.  Depending up on the status listed in the DB table, I give the user options

view file: dashboard.blade.php (snippet)

```
@foreach ($jobInterviews as $interviews)
    @if ($interviews->j == $job->id)
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>
        {{$interviews->contact_name}}
        @if ($interviews->status == 'interview request accepted')

    <a href="#"  class="btn btn-danger btn-small" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".mymodal{{ $interviews->interview_id }}">Hire</a>
       @elseif ($interviews->status == 'hired')
        <button id="complete" class="btn btn-info btn-small">Mark Project Complete</button>
        @endif
        </td>
        <td>{{$interviews->status}} </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
         ...
```

The problem that I am having is that to complete the job status change, I am calling the method and passing in the record id:

Still in dashboard.blade.php

```
<form action="../jobs/offer/{{$interviews->interview_id}}" method="post">
```

This is then routed through:

```
Route::post('/jobs/offer/{id}','JobController@jobOffer');
```

Everything works as I want it to but I don't think I am doing it right from a security stand point. Is there a better way to call the jobOffer method and change the status besides using the record id in the route when getting the data from an array i've iterated through?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Add it as a form variable, `<form action="../jobs/offer" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="{$interviews->interview_id}">` not as a route parameter, then access it the normal way - whatever laravels wrapper around `$_POST['id']` is

Comment: @user574632 can't users change the default value of a hidden field as well?

Comment: Yes they can - you ALWAYS need to validate user input. If you are worried that a user could edit another users details, then you need to refactor to include some check server side that the user can actually access the details, sudo code: `if(user->canEdit($id){//do edit}`

Comment: @user574632  ok, thanks. That clears up the issue for me. I appreciate it.

Comment: Sending bu action and route methods are under the control of the user as they appear in the url .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => array('JobController@jobOffer', $interviews->interview_id))) }}
    <!-- Rest of the form fields -->
{{ Form::close() }}
```

This way you don't need to add `csrf/_method` input manually and by default it's `METHOD` would be `POST` so you can omit that.

Comment: Is it possible to submit a form with the variable included like this through jquery?

Comment: Articles explains passing data i.e. associative array, from controller to view. http://www.devtrainings.com/2016/04/how-to-return-view-from-controller-in-laravel.html