# How to define email subject in email template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have email blade like this:

```
<?php
$title = 'title';
$text   = 'text';
?>

@include('emails.layouts.general')
```

In emails.layouts.general

```
<h1>{{$title}}</h1>
<p>{{$text}}</p>
```

I send email like :

```
$subject = 'some subject'

\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::send($template, [],
    function ($m) {
    $m->to('test@test.com', 'test test')->subject($subject);
});
```

Does anybody have idea how I could define subject in blade :

```
<?php
$subject = 'subject';
$title   = 'title';
$text    = 'text';
?>
```

and set this subject when send email ?

EDITED:

I need something like:
Set email subject in email blade:

```
<?php
$title   = 'title';
$text    = 'text';
$subject = 'subject';
Mail::setEmailSubjectForNextEmail($subject);
?>

@include('emails.layouts.general
```

or in controller :

```
$subject = somehowGetSubjectVariableFromTemplate($template);

\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::send($template, [],
    function ($m) use ($subject) {
    $m->to('test@test.com', 'test test')->subject($subject);
});
```

I want set subject variable in blade template, not in controller, because I have more than 50 emails and I want front developers only work(edit) with blade templates not with controllers.

Comment: how ? subject is set here : ->subject($subject);
I need to set subject somehow in template or pass from template to controller.

Comment: Have you tried using `{{$subject}}` in your blade file as suggested?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500020/passing-data-from-view-to-controller-in-laravel

Comment: Set your subject line in a language file then you can just read same value into your template and controller. You can then pass the language files to your front end guy he can fill in the copy text next to the labels

Comment: Solution for my problem: I created my own facade for sending mails and put email subjects and titles in lang file....

Answer (score 0):

Try use:

```
@php 
$message->setSubject('New subject');
@endphp
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass the `$subject` into the callback and into the template. The `subject` method sets the mail subject line it doesn't pass it into the email template

```
$subject = 'Your Subject';

Mail::send($template, ['subject'=>$subject,'other_thing'=>'what you like'], //this will pass it into the blade template
   function ($m) use($subject){ //you need to pass into the use clause to make the variable available in the scope of the callback
      $m->to('test@test.com', 'test test')->subject($subject); 
   }
);
```

You dont need to assign values to your variables at the top of the template either they will be available as long as you put them into the array in the second argument.

blade template:

```
<div>{{$subject}}</div> <!-- "Your Subject" -->
<span>{{$other_thing}}</span><!-- "what you like" -->
```

Comment: I want set subject variable in blade template, not in controller, because I have more than 50 emails and I want front developers only work(edit) with blade templates not with controllers.

Comment: I edited to make this clearer but this is exactly what I have shown. Pass it as the second argument of the `send` method

Comment: you defined subject in controller, i know hot to do this.

Comment: Are you saying you want to have a subject line hard coded into the blade template and pass it up to the controller? If so this is not possible (not without some horrible hack parsing the blade html) you would be better off using a language or config file and reading the value from there

Comment: lang or config file maybe would be good solution, but some subject will have variables so this is not option.